# I'm not sure why this isn't XML information isn't printing to the screen

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have written this code which is supposed to print the information from the xml file into a list for each faculty member. I want to eventually place all of these into a table, but need to know how to print them to the screen first.

```
function init() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseXML);
            var faculty = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faculty");
            var strOut = "<ul>";
            for (i = 0; i < faculty.length; i++) {
                var name = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].innerHTML;
                var title = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
                var office = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("office")[0].innerHTML;
                var phone = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].innerHTML;
                var email = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].innerHTML;

                strOut += "<li><a href = " + name + title + "</a></li>";
            }
            strOut += "<ul>";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strOut;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "faculty.xml", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
window.onload = init;
```

Here is the XML file:

```xml
<facultyInfo>
    <faculty>
        <name>Prof A</name>
        <title>Professor and Program Coordinator</title>
        <office>CI 555</office>
        <phone>(999-999-9999</phone>
        <email>ProfA@school.edu</email>
    </faculty>
    <faculty>
        <name>Prof B</name>
        <title>Visiting Professor</title>
        <office>CI 333</office>
        <phone>999-999-9999</phone>
        <email>ProfB@school.edu</email>
    </faculty>
</facultyInfo>
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by print it to the screen. the output you have here is already printed.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they mean they want the tabular data from the parsed XML displayed in the `#output` element on whatever page they're using. @SnakeySnake99 if you want proper help here, you need to provide all the relevant pieces of code for the problem, which includes the page you're trying to inject the results into.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
strOut += "<li><a href = " + name + title + "</a></li>";
```

... is both malformed and probably not what you intended. Between the missing quotes for the href attribute, missing the ">" to close off the `<a>` start, and not putting any text in between `<a></a>`, this results in a link tag where the link destination (href) is set, but the actual text to show to the user is not set. I don't see any links in your XML (maybe that is for the future), so for now you probably want something like this:

```
strOut += '<li><a href="">' + name + ', ' + title + '</a></li>';
```

Here is a quick demo with your XML input:

```html
<div id="output"></div>

<script>
var xmlString = '<facultyInfo> <faculty> <name>Prof A</name> <title>Professor and Program Coordinator</title> <office>CI 555</office> <phone>(999-999-9999</phone> <email>ProfA@school.edu</email> </faculty> <faculty> <name>Prof B</name> <title>Visiting Professor</title> <office>CI 333</office> <phone>999-999-9999</phone> <email>ProfB@school.edu</email> </faculty> </facultyInfo>';
var xmlDoc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(xmlString,'text/xml');

// var faculty = this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("faculty");
var faculty = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("faculty");
var strOut = "<ul>";

for (i = 0; i < faculty.length; i++){
    var name = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("name")[0].innerHTML;
    var title = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    var office = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("office")[0].innerHTML;
    var phone = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].innerHTML;
    var email = faculty[i].getElementsByTagName("email")[0].innerHTML;
    strOut += '<li><a href="">' + name + ', ' + title + '</a></li>';
}
strOut += "<ul>";
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = strOut;
</script>
```